# ajax call fails on second request to same url

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I'm making an Ajax to a C# method that works fine on first request but fails on second request. I have set cache: false on ajax request. I also added header

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { "Cache-Control": "no-cache" }
});
```

But nothing works. Can anyone help. This is my Ajax code

```
function GetproductsForBinding(ddlID) {    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'Default.aspx/BindProductsToDropdownlist?dummy="'+Date.now()+'"',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        cache:false,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            var data = JSON.parse(data.d);
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {                                            
            })                              
        },              
        error: function (msg, err, er) {
            debugger;
        }
    });
}
```

The second request fails and goes to error block and error says network error occured. Any help is much appreciated. I'm bagging my head for 2 days.

I'm making the second like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Default.aspx/ProcessPayment',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ PaymentProcessData: PaymentProcessData }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache: false,
    //beforeSend: function () {
    //    $('#loadingDiv').show();
    //},
    success: function (data) {
        GetproductsForBinding(1);
    },
    error: function (msg) {                   
    }

});
```

Comment: you dont need var data = JSON.parse(data.d);, as it is already a json object

Comment: on success add code => alert("success");   Check alert is coming 2nd time ,3rd time .

Comment: where is the code for second request ?

Comment: what is the error/status code that you are receiving? Can you post the error response?

Comment: first i'm calling the method on page load and then making the second request from another ajax function success block. The error code i'm getting is 13 i.e Dom Exception "Network error occurred".            Thanks for all your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer my self delaying the second call for 2 seconds works great!!!!

:)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).